# Selecting ListBox item returns null

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm populating my list using data binding in WPF and everything is working fine. But I can't get the string of the selected item in my ListBox.

Here's my code of the button where I'm trying to get the value of selected Item.

```
private void hexButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (imeiListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select IMEi from IMEI List!");
        }
        else
        {
            ListBoxItem myselectedItem= imeiListBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
            string text = myselectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And here's my XAML code of the ListBox.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="imeiListBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Devices}"  
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
          SelectionChanged="imeiListBox_SelectionChanged" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Imei}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is that *string text = myselectedItem.ToString();* is returning ***null***. How does one resolve that?

Comment: try `string text = imeiListBox.SelectedItem` ... then check the casting

Comment: Please show sample code for your `Device` class. Maybe you're overriding its ToString method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedItem` doesn't return a `ListBoxItem`. It returns an instance of the type (`Device` ?) where the `Imei` property is defined.

So you should cast to this type:

```
var myselectedItem= imeiListBox.SelectedItem as Device;
if (myselectedItem != null)
    string text = myselectedItem.Imei.ToString();
```

Or you could use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
dynamic myselectedItem= imeiListBox.SelectedItem;
string text = myselectedItem.Imei?.ToString();
```

Note that this will fail at runtime if `SelectedItem` returns anything else than an object with an `Imei` property. If you know the type, casting is preferable.

Comment: here the use of `dynamic` doesn't seem justified given the fact that it can be achieved using simple casting.

Comment: @CorentinPane: Yes. *Or* by using `dynamic`. Casting is undoubtedly nicer.

Answer (score 3):

The `imeiListBox.SelectedItem` will be an object with the same type as the items you put in the `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox`, probably a `Device` object looking at your code.

You have to cast it like

```cs
imeiListBox.SelectedItem as Device;
```

instead.